# Upgrading Application to Java 21 and Maven PMD Plugin Incompatibility

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, pmd

I'm encountering an issue while upgrading my application to Java 21. The existing Maven PMD Plugin (version 3.19.0) seems incompatible with Java 21.

Here's a breakdown of the problem:

**Upgrade Requirement:** My application needs to be upgraded to use Java 21.

**PMD Plugin Issue:** During the mvn clean install command, I receive an error message: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.19.0:pmd (pmd) on project domain: Execution pmd of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.19.0:pmd failed: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Unsupported targetJdk value '21'.

**Lack of Java 21 Support:** According to the Maven PMD Plugin documentation (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/targetJdk.html), supported versions only go up to Java 20. Java 21 compatibility is not explicitly listed.

Could you please advise on how to proceed with the upgrade given this PMD plugin limitation? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.19.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pmd</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>pmd</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pmd-check</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cpd</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cpd</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>cpd-check</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>21</targetJdk>
                    <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                    <minimumTokens>40</minimumTokens>
                    <minimumPriority>0</minimumPriority>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>${pmd.ruleset.relative.path}</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <excludeRoots>
                        <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources</excludeRoot>
                    </excludeRoots>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version 3.21.2 instead of the older 3.19.0?

Comment: Yes , I tried that version also but no luck

Comment: And are you sure the error is from the actual plugin or the PMD version in use?

Comment: You should check this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/upgrading-PMD-at-runtime.html and upgrade the pmd deps to most recent versions....

Comment: @M.Deinum How do I differentiate the error is from actual plugin or the PMD version in use?

Comment: Probably by enabling debug logs (running with `-X`. That way you will see the original error. I doubt the plugin will limit the java version, it will just pass it on to PMD, if you have a PMD version that doesn't support the version it will break (and report back through the plugin). Hence I would upgrade to a newer plugin **and** upgrade to the latest version of PMD. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/upgrading-PMD-at-runtime.html on how to specify the PMD version for the plugin. Seems you need the 7.0 RC version for Java 21 support.

Comment: PMD version is automatically taken based on maven-pmd-plugin version.  <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.21.2</version>. PMD version - 6.55.0 
 <version>3.19.0</version>. PMD version - 6.49.0

Comment: @RagaSGNur I'm using [basepom](https://github.com/basepom/basepom) and I've temporarily disabled PMD with `<basepom.check.skip-pmd>true</basepom.check.skip-pmd>`